# How to delete multiple Checked Listview items from sqlite database in android using baseAdapter

Tags: android, database, sqlite

i want to delete multiple checked listview item from sqlite database in android. i have extends baseAdapter for listview. can any one suggest me how can i delete multiple checked items from sqlite database.

Comment: `How to delete multiple Checked Listview items from sqlite database` **one by one**.

Answer (score 1):

```
SparseBooleanArray sba=new SparseBooleanArray(); // declare globally in adapter
convertview.onClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick()
{
 if(checkbox.isChecked())
 {
   sba.put(position,true);
 }
  else
 {
  sba.put(position,false);
 }

});
```

**on delete selected button click method**
ArrayList itemstodeletelist=new ArrayList();

```
deleteselectedbutton.onClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(){
  for(int position=0;position<array.size();position++) 
  {
     if(array.get(position))
     {
        itemstodeletelist.Add(itemslist[position]);
     }

   }
}
```

**Now in db loop delete method with for each item in `itemstodeletelist`**

Comment: rajan, please give me full code chenges in sqlite database also... so i can understand easily.